No Modules Loading in Powershell
I have been trying to fix this for a while now and nothing seems to work.
If I type get-installedmodule I can find all my installed modules.
If I type import-module I dont get any prompt which is as expected.
If I type get-module I can see whichever module I choose.
As soon as I try to use any of my installed modules, I get the following

winget : The term 'winget' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
function, script file, or operable program

This is happening with any modules I've installed since the device was rebuilt a year ago.
All was working fine just a few days ago?

Winget is not a PowerShell cmdlet

Microsoft.Winget.Client is indeed a powershell module. As im sure you're aware most anything can be made into a module. pswindowsupdate, exchangeonlinemanagement, microsoft.graph, all of them give the same error which does not occur on any other computer. obviously.

Microsoft.Winget.Client is indeed a PowerShell module, but winget is not a cmdlet exported by that module - it's the name of the native winget binary. To see the commands exported by the module, do Get-Command -Module Microsoft.Winget.Client

When you say "i try to use any of my installed modules", how, specifically, are you using them? Are you saying that invoking any cmdlet / function from any of the modules you've installed with Install-Module produces this error message? Only this error message, or does the cmdlet / function still run? What about cmdlets from other sources, such as the built-in ones? What about calls to external programs? Does the error message appear there too?
